# Google Dotnet API - Admin SDK Groups - Getting Bad Request Error

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

Just trying out to peruse the Google Dotnet API Admin SDK to work.

I am having some errors when I try to retrieve a listing of all Groups. I am still confused at the documentation (which methods or functions to use etc.).

The codes I have right now:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data;

namespace GoogleConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroup, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupReadonly  },
                    "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Tasks.Auth.Store")).Result;
            }

            var dirSvc = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Groups API Sample",
            });

            Groups myGroups = dirSvc.Groups.List().Execute();
```

Pretty much it errors out saying:

```
Unhandled Exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError 
Bad Request [400]
Errors: [Message [Bad Request] Location [ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]]
```

I've already enabled the necessary APIs in the Developer's Console.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Update:
I also tried this method (as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Admin_1_1Directory_1_1directory__v1_1_1GroupsResource_1_1ListRequest.html)):

```
Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.GroupsResource.ListRequest lreq = new GroupsResource.ListRequest(dirSvc);
            Groups grp2 = lreq.Execute();
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: 1.Can you add the fiddler output of the request and the response? 2.Also can you please check if it works from Google APIs Explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/directory.groups.list)

Comment: Side note way after the fact - You have to make sure your time of the server/computer doing the request is the same as Google's time on their servers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly set the domain of the request. The mistake is in assuming it would just search the global domain if you leave domain blank like the other types of requests do. In this case it instead tries to search for the groups of the customer, which is also blank. From a note in the [api spec](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups).

> When retrieving:
>
> - All groups for a sub-domain — Use the domain argument with the domain's name.
> - All groups for the account — Use the customer argument with either my_customer or the account's customerId value. As an account
>     administrator, use the string my_customer to represent your account's
>     customerId. If you are a reseller accessing a resold customer's
>     account, use the resold account's customerId. For the customerId value
>     use the account's primary domain name in the Retrieve all users in a
>     domain operation's request. The resulting response has the customerId
>     value.
> - Using both domain and customer arguments — The API returns all the groups for the domain.
> - **Not using the domain and customer arguments — The API returns all the groups for the account associated with my_customer. This is the
>     account customerId of the administrator making the API request.**

Example that works:

```
GroupsResource.ListRequest groupRequest = _service.Groups.List();
groupRequest.Domain = "YourDomain";
Groups domainGroups = groupRequest.Execute();
```

Example that does not work and will throw your exact same error:

```
GroupsResource.ListRequest groupRequest = _service.Groups.List();
Groups domainGroups = groupRequest.Execute();
```